# Verbatim and Bacground&TikZ compatibility problems

Tags: tikz-pgf, verbatim, backgrounds

If to compile below MWE, you'll get next error:

[image]

According the error message, the problem is `tikz` and `calc` library package, which looks like links with `background` package. Also, you will not find any dollar sigh in code of the MWE, which reads in the error message.

What is the problem?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{background}

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
Sub test3()
' test3 Macro
    Selection.InsertSymbol CharacterNumber:=8658, Unicode:=True, Bias:=0
    With Selection.OMaths(1).Functions.Add(Selection.Range, _
        wdOMathFunctionDelim, 1)
        .Delim.BegChar = 9001
        .Delim.SepChar = 0
        .Delim.EndChar = 9002
        .Delim.Grow = True
        .Delim.Shape = wdOMathShapeCentered
    End With
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.Font.Italic = wdToggle
    Selection.Font.Name = "ＭＳ ゴシック"
    Selection.Font.Bold = wdToggle
    Selection.TypeText Text:="test3()"
    Selection.Font.Bold = wdToggle
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.InsertSymbol CharacterNumber:=8658, Unicode:=True, Bias:=0
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=3
End Sub

Sub test2()
' test2 Macro
    Selection.InsertSymbol CharacterNumber:=8658, Unicode:=True, Bias:=0
    With Selection.OMaths(1).Functions.Add(Selection.Range, _
        wdOMathFunctionDelim, 1)
        .Delim.BegChar = 9001
        .Delim.SepChar = 0
        .Delim.EndChar = 9002
        .Delim.Grow = True
        .Delim.Shape = wdOMathShapeCentered
    End With
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.Font.Italic = wdToggle
    Selection.Font.Name = "ＭＳ ゴシック"
    Selection.Font.Bold = wdToggle
    Selection.TypeText Text:="test2()"
    Selection.Font.Bold = wdToggle
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.InsertSymbol CharacterNumber:=8658, Unicode:=True, Bias:=0
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=3
End Sub

Sub Test1()
' Test1 Macro
    Selection.InsertSymbol CharacterNumber:=8658, Unicode:=True, Bias:=0
    With Selection.OMaths(1).Functions.Add(Selection.Range, _
        wdOMathFunctionDelim, 1)
        .Delim.BegChar = 9001
        .Delim.SepChar = 0
        .Delim.EndChar = 9002
        .Delim.Grow = True
        .Delim.Shape = wdOMathShapeCentered
    End With
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.Font.Italic = wdToggle
    Selection.Font.Name = "ＭＳ ゴシック"
    Selection.Font.Bold = wdToggle
    Selection.TypeText Text:="Test1()"
    Selection.Font.Bold = wdToggle
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.InsertSymbol CharacterNumber:=8658, Unicode:=True, Bias:=0
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=3
End Sub
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the problem appears because your code is longer than one page and the system doesn't know how to break it. I divided it in three `\begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}` environtments with `\newpage` between second and third and it worked.